# Pushing to multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays

Can anyone help me how to insert multidimensional array to my array in php?
here is the sample code:

```
$valuesNeeded = array(
    array('a', 'a', 'a')
);

$entryOne = 'b';
$entryTwo = 'b';
$entryThree = 'b';
```

the values should be the same if I do this:

```
$valuesNeeded = array(
    array('a', 'a', 'a'), array('b','b','b')
);
```

the reason for this is the 2nd array will be given via input so i dont know how to do this. help please.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put your values to new array and assign them as new element of your `$valuesNeeded` array:

```
$valuesNeeded[] = array($entryOne, $entryTwo, $entryThree);
```

OR

```
$newRow = array();
$newRow[] = $entryOne;
$newRow[] = $entryTwo;
$newRow[] = $entryThree;
$valuesNeeded[] = $newRow;
```

Answer (score 4):

use array_push

```
 array_push($valuesNeeded,[$entryOne,$entryTwo,$entryThree]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> @Rey Norbert Besmonte simply make an array with these three entry and
>   insert it in $valuesNeeded array like below

```
<?php

$valuesNeeded = array(
    array('a', 'a', 'a')
);

$entryOne = 'b';
$entryTwo = 'b';
$entryThree = 'b';
$valuesNeeded[] = array($entryOne, $entryTwo, $entryThree);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$valuesNeeded = array(array('a', 'a', 'a'));
$entryOne = 'b';
$entryTwo = 'b';
$entryThree = 'b';
$valuesNeeded[] = [$entryOne, $entryTwo, $entryThree];
```

This should solve your problem.